# Excel macro for replace points with commas

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to make a macro where I select one column and only for that column i replace all points for commas and also i want to delete letter "g" which is added to all cells in that column

So instead of having 24.56 g i want to have 24,56

I made a macro

```
Sub Macro5()

Columns("F").Replace What:="g", _
                        Replacement:="", _
                        LookAt:=xlPart, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        MatchCase:=False, _
                        SearchFormat:=False, _
                        ReplaceFormat:=False
Columns("F").Replace What:=".", _
                        Replacement:=",", _
                        LookAt:=xlPart, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        MatchCase:=False, _
                        SearchFormat:=False, _
                        ReplaceFormat:=False

End Sub
```

When I perform this task manually using find and replace it works fine but my problem is when i run this macro and all the cells in that columns lose their comma

so cells with 123,456 change to 123456
and cells with 21.56 g change to 2156

Could you tell me what i'm doing wrong please?

Comment: Have you attempted to format the column?  `columns(6).numberformat="#.##0"` etc?

Comment: Is your decimal separator a dot or a comma?

Comment: Is your result supposed to be a number, or a string?  If the latter, format the cell as text before doing the Replace.  If the former,  this may just be a formatting problem In any event, more information is required.

Comment: Hi, thank for your answers, the decimal separator is by comma and the final result has to be a number because i perform a mathematical operation.

Comment: @Adriiboom How does the data get onto your excel sheet?  If you are importing it from a CSV or TXT file, for example, you should be setting the separator during the import routine, so that Excel will properly interpret the data.  If by some other method, please clarify.  Also, please start your comments with `@name` so that the person to whom you are responding will be notified of your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is given by Cyril

Just have to add

```
columns(6).numberformat="#.##0"
Columns("F").Replace What:="g", _
                    Replacement:="", _
                    LookAt:=xlPart, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                    MatchCase:=False, _
                    SearchFormat:=False, _
                    ReplaceFormat:=False
```

And it works, this change the points for commas also and doesn't delete the other data.

Thanks to all.